# Unicode support in PySide

Tags: qt, unicode, pyside

I am working on with PySide 1.21 and Qt 4.85 using PyCharm 3.1 with Python 2.7.6. I would like my application to support unicode so at the beginning of the ​code I type:

```
#--coding: utf-8 --

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import math

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)

        self.resultsList = QTextBrowser()
        self.resultsInput = QLineEdit("Enter an expression and press return key")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.resultsList)
        layout.addWidget(self.resultsInput)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.resultsInput.selectAll() # or
        self.resultsInput.setFocus()

        self.resultsInput.returnPressed.connect(self.compute)

    def compute(self):
        try:
            text = self.resultsInput.text()
            self.resultsList.append("{0} =<b>{1}</b>".format(text, eval(text)))

        except:
            self.resultsList.append("<font color=red><b>Expression Invalid</b></font>")
            # self.resultsList.append("<font color=red><b>格式错误</b></font>") ## unicode

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = Form()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

When I replaced the code at the except block using unicode, the unicode does not show up properly in the program. Where did I get wrong? Is the problem with the PySide, Qt or some setting error? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get it sorted. It is simple, in python 2.7, when you want to support unicode, you need to declare:

```
#--coding: utf-8 --
```

at the beginning of the program, also when hard coding with in the application, you need to write "u" in front of the code. For example:

```
 self.resultsList.append("<font color=red><b>Expression Invalid</b></font>")
```

need to write as:

```
self.resultsList.append(u"<font color=red><b>格式错误</b></font>")
```

just a little "u" and the problem is solved.